# Gaussian process with two dimensional feature array as the input in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, kernel

I need to implement GPR (Gaussian process regression) in Python using sci-kit learn library.

My input X has two features. 
Ex. X=[race, BMI]. And output is one dimension y=[age_expectancy]

I want to use two Kernels; RBF and Matern, such that RBF uses the 'race' feature while Matern use the 'age' feature. 
I tried the following:

```
X = np.matrix([[1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5],[4, 7.],[ 9,8.], [1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5],[4, 7.],[ 9,8.],[1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5],[4, 7.],[ 9,8.]]).T


y=[84,  42, 47, 55,  25,  78, 52, 25, 75, 22,  45, 45, 88,  56, 77, 58,  48,  79]


kernel = R(X[0]) * M(X[1])

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)


gp.fit(X, y)
```

But this gives an error 'ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 18]'.

I tried several methods but could not find a solution. Really appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your whole code but here is my suggestion.

Seems like your input is a matrix AND a list. The **shape** of the matrix **X** is **(2,18)** and the **size** of the list **y** is **18**.

Therefore I recommend converting the list into array with explictly defined shape of (1,18). Run this:

```
y = np.reshape(y,(1,18))
```

before `gp.fit(X, y)` and let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing the `.T` on the X?

This changes the shape of X from (18,2) to (2,18) and hence the error.

The following is working for me (Just removed the `.T` from end of X):

```
X = np.matrix([[1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5], [4, 7.], [9,8.], [1.,2], 
               [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5], [4,7.], [ 9,8.], [1.,2], [3.,4], 
               [5.,1], [6.,5], [4,7.], [9,8.]])

y = [84, 42, 47, 55, 25, 78, 52, 25, 75, 22, 45, 45, 88, 56, 77, 
     58, 48, 79]

gp.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: isn't it because of the way the OP defines the kernel?